# In this code i am not getting customers name lists and also city name . why?

Tags: html, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-directive

In this code i am not getting the un-ordered list of customers nor city name

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html data-ng-app="">

    <head>
        <title>Using AngularJS Directives and Data Binding </title>
    </head>

    <body data-ng-init="customers=[{name:'Rishabh Shrivas',city:'New Delhi'},{name:'Rishabh Bharadawaj',city:'Noida'},{name:'Rishabh Sen ,city:'Gurgaon'}] ">
        Name :
        <br />
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name " /> {{ name }}
        <br />

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:{name} "> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
        </ul>


        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>

    </body>


    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have missing ' in ng-init and dont use {} in filter.

```
<body data-ng-init="customers=[{name:'Rishabh Shrivas',city:'New Delhi'},{name:'Rishabh Bharadawaj',city:'Noida'},{name:'Rishabh Sen' ,city:'Gurgaon'}]">
        Name :
        <br />
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name " /> {{ name }}
        <br />

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name "> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
        </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: i used ng-init  <body data-ng-init=

Comment: yah that's finebut see this {name:'Rishabh Sen ,city:'Gurgaon'}.  After Sen you missing single close to complete it

Answer (score 0):

Check this one

Your filter should be like this

```
data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name "
```

UPDATED HTML :

```
<body data-ng-init="customers=[{name:'Rishabh Shrivas',city:'New Delhi'},{name:'Rishabh Bharadawaj',city:'Noida'},{name:'Rishabh Sen' ,city:'Gurgaon'}] ">
        Name :
        <br />
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name " /> {{ name }}
        <br />

        <ul>
            <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter:name "> {{ cust.name }} - {{ cust.city }} </li>
        </ul>




    </body>
```